# Get most recent status for each server in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using eloquent query builder and I am trying to get the most recent status for each server, I have a `servers` table that has a one to many relationship with my `server_statuses` table. My current 'solution' is based off the laracon online advanced eloquent presentation, but it is not returning anything from my database, attached below is my Server model, AppServiceProvider, and Controller.

What am I doing wrong here? I cant seem to figure it out.

Controller:

```
$recent = Server::WithLastStatusDate()
            ->OrderBy('server_id');
```

Model:

```
public function scopeWithLastStatusDate($query){

    $query ->addSubSelect('last_status_date', ServerStatus::select('created_at')
        ->whereRaw('server_id = servers.id')
        ->latest()
    );
}
```

AppServiceProvider:

```
Builder::macro('addSubSelect', function ($column, $query) {
    if (is_null($this->getQuery()->columns)) {
        $this->select($this->getQuery()->from.'.*');
    }

    return $this->selectSub($query->limit(1)->getQuery(), $column);
});
```

Again any help would be much appreciated, Thank you for your time!

EDIT:::

Im not the best at raw sql but here is what the previous should be in raw sql.

```
SELECT "servers".*, (SELECT "created_at" FROM "server_statuses" WHERE server_id = servers.id ORDER by "created_at" DESC LIMIT 1) as "last_server_status" FROM "servers" ORDER BY servers.id
```

I downloaded and used the tool debugbar and it seems as if the DB query is never being executed at all.

[image]

EDIT 2:: Changed the model and controller now, I am getting all of the public servers, but it is returning the servers that have no status also.

Model Updated:

```
public function scopeWithLastStatusDate($query){

    $query->addSubSelect('last_status_date', ServerStatus::select('servers.name')
        ->whereRaw('server_id = servers.id')
        ->latest()
    );
}
```

Controller Updated:

```
$servers = Server::WithLastStatusDate()
    ->OrderBy('servers.id')
    ->where('servers.isPublic', '=', 1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: You build top servers minecraft?))

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir laravel 5.6

Comment: You can debug a query using ->toSql() and ->getBindings().   Your `$query ->addSubSelect('last_status_date', ServerStatus::select('created_at')` isn't closed.  The where() and latest() call aren't contained on the subquery...

Comment: Is the result just empty or is there an error?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir empty

Comment: @Devon can you elaborate?

Comment: On what part?  I think if you look into toSql(), you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: But `Server::all()` works? Shouldn't `->OrderBy('server_id')` be `->OrderBy('servers.id')`?

Comment: @devon I just started using the tool debugbar, and i found a interetsing result. editing the op to reflect my findings.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir changed to that, and same result.

Comment: You have to execute the query with `->get()`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Made some progress, I will post updated code and screenshot of issue in the OP

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir nevermind, that was an error on my view end, it is working now, Thank you so much for the help! if you post my code above as answer I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the solution with the edit of the original post